# JQuery doesn't work with components loaded by $.post()

Tags: php, jquery

I'am creating a page that load other page inside a div, without refresh, as a template. But the components that were designed by JQuery-Ajax request does not interact with any function created by me with JQuery, it is as if the selectors of these components do not exist.

Below I am creating a function to load the page in the center of the template:

```
function carregaUrl2(url) {

    var data = $("form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#divCentral").html(data);
    });

}
```

Below the function test, just to interact with components created by JQuery-Ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("form").change(function(e) {
        alert("SUBMIT FORM");
        e.preventDefault();

        return false;

    });

    $("select").click(function() {
        alert("INPUT CLICK");
    });

});
```

I've searching for solutions, but has been hard!

Could you help me, please?

Comment: post you related HTML code too

Comment: I don't think there is a change event on the form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements don't exist when your ready function fires. You need to use a delegate instead, as it allows binding to objects created after the handler is registered.

```
$("#divCentral").on("click", "select", function() {
    alert("INPUT CLICK");
});
```

[.on() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)